# Carousel slide on keyboard click

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I would like to make my owl carousel slide on keyboard click, specially on arrow left/right. 
How can i do it?
My JS:

```
      loop: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        autoplay: true,
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        dots: true,
        items: 1,
        itemsDesktop: false,
        itemsDesktopSmall: false,
        itemsTablet: true,
        itemsMobile: false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(document).keydown( function(eventObject) {
   if(eventObject.which==37) {//left arrow
      $('.owl-prev').click();//emulates click on prev button
  } else if(eventObject.which==39) {//right arrow
     $('.owl-next').click();//emulates click on next button
   }
});
```

Refer : https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/110